# Selenium find similar links based on conditional tags

Tags: python, selenium

I need to find a specific href link below is an example of 3 rows. The rows are very similar but they are a bit different. I need the link to the Product ABC that is MSSQL and CS

```
<tr>
<th class=\"align-middle\" scope=\"row\">
<span class=\"badge bg-primary position-relative py-2\">Product ABC
<span class=\"position-absolute top-0 start-100 translate-middle badge rounded-pill bg-secondary\">P3
</span>
</span>
</th>
<td class=\"align-middle small\">MySQL</td>
<td class=\"align-middle small\">MR</td>
<td class=\"align-middle small\">
<div class=\"btn-group\" role=\"group\">
<span data-bs-placement=\"left\" data-bs-toggle=\"tooltip\" title=\"\" data-bs-original-title=\"Show Application\" aria-label=\"Show Application\">
<a class=\"btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary\" href=\"/repo/applications/328\">
<svg class=\"bi flex-shrink-0\" height=\"18\" role=\"img\" width=\"18\">
<use href=\"#icon_eye\"></use>
</svg>
</a>
</span>
</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th class=\"align-middle\" scope=\"row\">
<span class=\"badge bg-primary position-relative py-2\">Product ABC
<span class=\"position-absolute top-0 start-100 translate-middle badge rounded-pill bg-secondary\">P3
</span>
</span>
</th>
<td class=\"align-middle small\">MySQL</td>
<td class=\"align-middle small\">MR</td>
<td class=\"align-middle small\">
<div class=\"btn-group\" role=\"group\">
<span data-bs-placement=\"left\" data-bs-toggle=\"tooltip\" title=\"\" data-bs-original-title=\"Show Application\" aria-label=\"Show Application\">
<a class=\"btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary\" href=\"/repo/applications/329\">
<svg class=\"bi flex-shrink-0\" height=\"18\" role=\"img\" width=\"18\">
<use href=\"#icon_eye\"></use>
</svg>
</a>
</span>
</div>
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<th class=\"align-middle\" scope=\"row\">
<span class=\"badge bg-primary position-relative py-2\">Product ABC
<span class=\"position-absolute top-0 start-100 translate-middle badge rounded-pill bg-secondary\">P3
</span>
</span>
</th>
<td class=\"align-middle small\">SQLServer</td>
<td class=\"align-middle small\">CS</td>
<td class=\"align-middle small\">
<div class=\"btn-group\" role=\"group\">
<span data-bs-placement=\"left\" data-bs-toggle=\"tooltip\" title=\"\" data-bs-original-title=\"Show Application\" aria-label=\"Show Application\">
<a class=\"btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary\" href=\"/repo/applications/330\">
<svg class=\"bi flex-shrink-0\" height=\"18\" role=\"img\" width=\"18\">
<use href=\"#icon_eye\"></use>
</svg>
</a>
</span>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

I currently have this

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//tr[.//span[contains(.,'Product ABC')]]//a")
element.get_attribute("href")
```

The code above works but is returns the first Product ABC that it sees in some cases that is ok but some times its incorrect. How do i make sure i filter my xpath so I return the href applications/330 and not the others.

Comment: Yes this question is similar to last question. I posted the previous questions as well. I got a good answer from the expert but i then realized that similar data would return wrong href link. The expert him/her self advised me to open a new question. Similar question be addressing a different issue now .  Please reconsider reopening thank you.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium This is really a new question. The author here is asking about new issues. We resolved several issues there, now he has new, additional problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to select the `a` element containing the desired `href` link based both on `Product ABC` value **and** on `SQLServer` value the XPath locator will be as following:

```py
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//tr[.//span[contains(.,'Product ABC')] and .//td[contains(.,'SQLServer')]]//a")
```

In case you will need to **add** dependency of `CS` too, it can be added in the same way here:

```py
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//tr[.//span[contains(.,'Product ABC')] and .//td[contains(.,'SQLServer')] and .//td[contains(.,'CS')]]//a")
```

In case you will need to locate the link containing element based on `MySQL` or/and on `MR` this can be done in the same manner.